# Wcf DataTable method result

Tags: c#, wcf, datatable

I'm new to WCF, and I have to return data from SQL, without knowing table schema.
I wanted to return DataTable from method, but I found that this is not a good practice.
So my question is what is the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about your situation. However, I suggest you should mapping data inside datatable into a simple object, mark it as `Datacontract` and transfer it as remote object, some of relevant techniques at here are [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) and [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (Data Transfer Object) conceptual.

You can take reference from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx) the article related to DTO which explain the case study why we should apply DTO when transfer remote objects.

From my experience, [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) lightweight, easy to configure and setup to transfer through WCF as well as traditional technical on network as Socket, pipeline.

You can look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/468354/WCF-example-for-inserting-and-displaying-data-from) from Code project it will help you understand and figure out the best way transfer data by apply [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)

Hope this help.